# SharePoint 2013 - Error while inserting data

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-addin, apps-development

I am new to SharePoint App. I have created one app with CRUD operations. While I try to insert data I am getting following error

---

### Message from webpage

### {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-2146232832, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"Failed to create a list item for this external list based on the Entity (External Content Type) 'tblBillingPoints' in EntityNamespace 'TimeSheetModel'. Details:  Message from External System : 'Forbidden'.\"}}}","status":500,"statusText":"error"}

### OK

My code is as below:

```
create: function (bid, billing) {
       // alert(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl +
                        "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('tblBillingPoints')/items",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify(
                {
                    '__metadata': {
                        'type': 'SP.Data.TblBillingPointsListItem'
                    },
                    'ID': bid,
                    'BillingPoint': billing
                }),
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: function () {
                REST.FormFiller.clear();
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(err));
            }
        });
    }
```

Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the ID column of a SharePoint list item. It is a default column for which SharePoint generates Ids internally since they have to be unique.

If you want to store the value of 'bid' variable somewhere, you will have to create another custom column to store it.

Comment: Thanks Vardhaman for your reply, I modified code as "create: function (hid, hname) {$.ajax({url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl +"/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('tblHolidays')/items",type: "POST",contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",data: JSON.stringify({'__metadata': {'type': 'SP.Data.TblHolidaysListItem'},'HID': hid,'HDesc': hname}),headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose","X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()},success: function () {REST.FormFiller.clear();},error: function (err) {alert(JSON.stringify(err));}});}". Still I have the same issue. Please help.

Comment: Please add more details to your question. 1) Is the list tblBillingPoints in your app web or your host web? 2) Is it an external list?

Comment: It is sharepoint hosted app. I am trying to update information to SQL table. My table tblBillingPoints has field as "ID". I don't want to change the field name. So, I created another method with table "tblHolidays".

Comment: Thanks again. I really appreciate your prompt response. It is sharepoint hosted app. I am trying to update information to SQL table. My table tblBillingPoints has field as "ID". I don't want to change the field name in the existing table. So, I created new table "tblHolidays" with HID, and HName for this CRUD operation.